# binaryTree insert and remove - C

Tags: c, insert, binary-tree, removeall

I have done insert a node and delete a tree with a tutorial. I test it and it works fine. However I can't understand why I need to pass by reference the root in insert, but in deleteAll just the pointer. Because I think that passing just the pointer its a value reference and then every change is only seen in the function.

```
typedef struct node{
    int element;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*tTree;

void insert(tTree *myTree, int element){
  if(*myTree == NULL){
    myTree= (tTree)malloc(sizeof(*myTree));
    myTree->element = element;
    myTree->left = NULL;
    myTree->right = NULL;   
  }
  else{
    int treeElement = (*myTree)->element;
    if( treeElement > element){
      insert(&(*myTree)->left, element);
    }
    else{
      insert(&(*myTree)->right, element);
    }
  }
}



void deleteAll(tTree myTree){
    if(myTree != NULL){
        deleteAll(myTree->right);
        deleteAll(myTree->left);
        free(myTree);
    }
}

int size(tTree myTree){
    if (myTree != NULL){
        return 1 + size(myTree->right) + size(myTree->left);    
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(){

  tTree root = NULL;
  insert(&root,3);
  insert(&root,2);
  insert(&root,4);
  insert(&root,1);
  printf("Number of nodes: %d\n",size(root));   
  deleteAll(root);
    root = NULL;
  printf("Number of nodes: %d\n",size(root));   
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: It is simple, by signing functions, insert receives a pointer to the structure while the delete only gets the structure. I recommend reading about pointer arithmetic and its use in every case

Comment: Other bad practices is a new in C  because you are  mix with POO and Structured programming

Comment: thats the variable name.

Comment: @Joseph, 'new' is a keyword in C++.   To avoid confusion (and compile/runtime problems if you use a C++ capable compiler) do not mis-use the keyword names of one language within a program targeted for the  other language

Comment: you may notice that 'tTree' gives no indication what so ever that it is actually a pointer.   This is one of the 'many' problems with using 'typedef' on struct definitions.   This kind of problem will be most noticeable in 6 months (or 6 years) when another program has to maintain your code.   Even now, I had to look several times before realizing the code had created a pointer using a typedef statement on a struct.   Now, some 'programmers' cannot type very well, so they try to minimize the amount of typing by using a 'typedef' just so they do not have to type 'struct ' several times.

Comment: @user3629249Do not spend to explain, I just wanted to know so it seems, because if you keep looking at the code to use malloc is pretty bad and that makes the little knowledge of C, but neither was interested in learning or correct the name of the variable

Comment: @santiago92 I didn't change it because I though you didn't see that the variable was named "new". I will change it, for others not make the same mistake. Sometimes when we wrote comments in forums like this the way they are written are different than the way we would have say it.

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, I know is not the best way but I had to do it like that because is the way that the struct was defined in the book to show the uses of typedef. I definitely prefer other forms. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Its ok ,but remember for the next time  that in most OOP languages the word new is reserved, so it is not available to use it for a local variable name :)

Comment: @santiago92 yes, you are right. Thanks for your advice. Also I read you said something about Malloc. I use it like that because I had seen that's correct. I tested the program with valgrind and the output was that the allocation and dellocation was correct. Maybe you know something that I am forgetting.

Comment: Sorry expressed me wrong, malloc is properly used, I see something complex is the kind of thing that solves the sizeof () function, usually this is used to determine the size in bytes of different types of data, so right to put sizeof(tTree)instead of sizeof(* new), only is a  advice for future implementations, do not get me wrong, Greetings

Comment: `myTree= (tTree)malloc(sizeof(*myTree));` you got confused by your own typedeffed pointer here. (there is a level of indirection missing on both sides)

Comment: @wildplasser I was having some memory leaks, so I read here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964658/c-malloc-valgrind-invalid-write-of-size?rq=1 It says that definition is best in memory, and also was a solution to my memory leak.
I don't know if it is right.

Comment: Now I see: you edited it in. The original version with `new` as a variable name seemed correct. The pointer cast does more harm than good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deletion needs only the pointer for the statements it executes.  It is not passing any information back to the calling function.  However, your insertion function *allocates* if needed, and in that case must pass back the allocated pointer to the caller.

Comment: `typedef struct node{
    int element;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*tTree;
` can you explain the `*tTree` part? This syntax is new to me

Comment: I thought that was the reason but I wasn't sure. So, like deletion needs only to free memory its correct to pass only the pointer. Thanks!

Comment: *tTree is infrequent the best practice is typedef struct { fields of structs }name_structs;
name_structs *str;

Comment: Thats the same as saying:
typedef struct node *tTree.

So now you can use tTree as an alias of  struct node *.

struct node * variable  = tTree variable